Job offer USA without interview
what happened with the job? Was real offer or scam for 200 euros?
I find same offer and wondering if it's true,please advice!
Thank you

What job? How would we know what you are talking about? But generally speaking, if you paid money for a job offer, it was a scam, sorry.

This question lacks details.... Did you pay 200 Euros to someone for a job offer?

Yes you were scammed. Consider it a tuition on learning to be more vigilant and it will pay itself back in a short time.
